# Prioritize posts in query by meta keys?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, query

I have a CPT called `jobs`. In my single jobs page I am counting page views with these functions:

```
/********* Post Views counter  ***********/
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);

if(!function_exists('wptest_setPostViews')){
    function wptest_setPostViews($postID) {
        $count_key = 'post_views_count';
        $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
        if($count==''){
            $count = 0;
            delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
            add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        }else{
            $count++;
            update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
        }
    }
}

function wptest_get_post_views($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0";
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Now, besides that I can set some of my jobs to be featured, and some don't have to be. So they have post meta value `wptest_job_is_featured`.

Now I'd like to have, out of all my job posts, 2 at the top that are featured, and also have highest views, but to pick randomly from them somehow, and below I'd have 4 non featured job posts picked randomly.

What I've done is I made 2 queries - featured and non featured ones.

```
$feat_query = array(
    'post_type'      => 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'rand',
    'meta_key'       => 'wptest_job_is_featured',
    'meta_value'     => 1,
);

$query = array(
    'post_type'      => 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
    'meta_key'       => 'wptest_job_is_featured',
    'meta_value'     => 0,
);
```

and I'm just showing my featured first, and non featured second.

Now how can I get my featured posts to show most viewed posts, but to shuffle between most viewed posts, so that I have randomly shown featured posts, but so that the ones which have been visited most, are shown more often?

Is this even possible? Since randomly ordering posts and ordering them by page views seem opposite?

This is my clients idea, and I don't know if it can be done.

I've tried this

```
$feat_query = array(
    'post_type'      => 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'order'          => 'rand',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'wptest_job_is_featured',
            'value'   => 1,
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'wptest_get_post_views',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order'   => 'DESC',
        ),
    ),
);
```

But that doesn't work. Can I somehow combine this all to one query? Featured and non featured + most viewed on top?